# Call parent virtual function from child overriden one

Tags: delphi

I have virtual function `Hello()` defined in parent and also in child class. How to call parent Hello() from child Hello()?

```
TParent = class (TComponent)
public
  procedure Hello(); virtual;
end;

TChild = class (TParent)
public
  procedure Hello(); 
end;


procedure TChild.Hello;
begin
  //call parent Hello();
end;
```

Comment: Please attend to compiler warnings, particularly to *TChild.Hello **hides** virtual method*

Answer (score 1):

You must call the inherited method. You also forget to add the **override** attribute:

```
program Project1;
type
  TParent = class
    procedure Hello(); virtual;
  end;

  TChild = class (TParent)
    procedure Hello();override;
    procedure Olleh;
  end;

  procedure TParent.Hello;
  begin
    writeln('pt');
  end;

  procedure TChild.Hello;
  begin
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TChild.Olleh;
  begin
    inherited Hello;
  end;

var child: TChild;
begin
  child := TChild.Create;
  child.Olleh;
  child.Hello;
  readln;
end.
```

Alternatively you can call the parent method "Hello", like in `Olleh`, by explicitely specifying the method to call. Usually in an overidden method `inherited` is naked, but sometime you have to explicitly call one method (e.g in case of mutiple constructors or overloads).

Comment: Remember that `Hello` is virtual and so `TParent(self).Hello` is dispatched based on the runtime type rather than the compile time type. Which means that `TParent(self).Hello` is identical to `Hello`. In other words, that part of your answer is confusing and misleading. Also, what's with downcasting? Who ever does that?

Comment: The initial question is ambiguous, I thought that either the OP's forget the **override** or the OP wish was to downcast. So I put the two solutions.

Comment: You don't understand my point. Read my comment again and compare the output of your program with a modified version that replaces `TParent(self).Hello` with `Hello`

Comment: Ok I've corrected the mistake. This is C downcast way. My bad. by `TParent(self).Hello` I meant `inherited Hello`.